# Helper ShowTree Displaying Child Items 2 Times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, recursion, html-helper

I am using @Helper ShowTree in my Project but I have problem with child items. In my view , child items displaying 2 times and look like parent menu. I looked samples in site, but not find difference. Where is my wrong ?

**MyEntity**

```
public class Kategori
    {
        public Kategori()
        {
            this.Children = new List<Kategori>();
        }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int ParentID { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Kategori> Children { get; set; }


    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {


        context = new CrudContext();
        List<Kategori> kategoriler= context.Kategoriler.ToList();


        return View(kategoriler);
    }
```

I think my problem is in my View.

View

```
@model List<JQueryDataTableCrud.Models.Kategori>
@RecursiveMenu(Model)

<div>
    @helper RecursiveMenu(List<JQueryDataTableCrud.Models.Kategori> kategoriler)
        {
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in kategoriler)
        {

                <li>
                    <span>@item.Name</span>

                    @if (item.Children.Any() && item.Children != null)
                    {

                        @RecursiveMenu(item.Children)

                    }

                </li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
}

</div>
```

**Result**

```
.Elektronik
  -Cep Telefonu
  -Mutfak
.Bilgisayar
.Cep Telefonu
.Mutfak
```

Comment: Are the child items stored on the same db table? What does the list contents hold before the recursion?

Comment: @Jasen Yes in same table. I dont have other table for menu. I posted my POCO.

Comment: Add a debugger stop and examine the list before returning to the view.

Comment: @Jasen I take 4 row count in my controller.

Comment: You need to identify and suppress the two child items from the query. They should be accounted for as children of the other two items.

Comment: @Jasen How can I do this ? I tried parentID==0 in my condition, I saw 2 items. Child condition not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're storing all of your `Kategori` in the same table, then you'll need a way to distinguish a parent from child in the initial query.

```
var kategoriler = context.Kategoriler.Where(k => k.ParentID == 0).ToList();

/*
.Elektronik
  -Cep Telefonu
  -Mutfak
.Bilgisayar
*/
```

That should restrict the top-level to the two parent items. This assumes you set `ParentID = 0`; This also assumes your context populates the `Children`.

Your recursive routine should be fine

```
@helper RecursiveMenu(List<JQueryDataTableCrud.Models.Kategori> kategoriler)
{
    @foreach (var item in kategoriler)
    {
        <span>@item.Name</span>

        @if (item.Children.Any() && item.Children != null)
        {
            @RecursiveMenu(item.Children)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my code like yours but no item displaying in my view.

Comment: I've omitted the html for clarity.

Comment: I wrote with html tags but I didnt understand. Where do I write my kategori for display in view ? I cant see code about this.

Comment: I wrote span blog to my code before you edited your post :)  Thank you so much